# If a function never returns is it valid to omit a return statement

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Consider a function `foo()` that might never exit:

```
int foo(int n) {
    if(n != 0) return n;
    else for(;;); /* intentional infinite loop */

    return 0; /* (*) */
}
```

Is it valid C to omit the final return-statement? Will it evoke undefined behavior if I leave out that final statement?

Comment: It might give a compiler warning omitting it.

Comment: What's wrong with that `return 0;` ?

Comment: @MM. That's what I want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it does return without a return statement there is no UB unless you use the return value.

Comment: Really? Can you quote the C standard.

Comment: in ISO C99, this is 6.9.1§12: "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
the caller, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Virgile: Nice quote. Where can I access to ISO-C99 online?

Comment: @MM, at http://www.lysator.liu.se/c you'll find a cornucopia of C resources, including last drafts of various standards.

Comment: Best online copy is http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html for C99 and http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html for C11.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately pdf is an extremely unpleasant format to navigate. I think the html conversions I linked to are a lot more convenient/useful, but of course they're unofficial.

Answer (score 3):

You can omit the last `return` statment which is after an indefinite loop. But you may be getting compilation warning like not all path are returning. Its not good to have an indefinite loop in a function. Keep one condition to break the loop.

If that indefinite loop is really required in that case anyway the `return` statement after that is a dead code. Removing that will not be undefinite behaviour.

Comment: The infinite loop is intentional in this example.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-`void` function, it is valid to have no `return` statements at all or that not all the paths have a `return` statement.

For example:

```
// This is a valid function definition.
int foo(void)
{
}
```

or

```
// This is a valid function definition.
int bar(void)
{
    if (printf(""))
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but reading the return value of `foo` is undefined behavior.

```
foo();  // OK
int a = foo();  // Undefined behavior
int b = bar();  // OK
```